# Content deployment job failed.The remote Web service request failed with this message : 'The operation has timed out'

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, content-deployment

I am trying to Deploy Content from source to destination site collection. I am getting following Error:

```
Content deployment job 'Test Deployment Job' failed.The remote Web service request failed with this message : 'The operation has timed out'.
```

My Source Site is Team Site and Destination site is blank site
[image]

My Web.Config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="252428800"/>
         </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are both sites in same farm, same Web applications?

Comment: They are in same farm, but on different web applications

Comment: How big the content you trying to export?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically this issue occurs when you have a large amount of content for export. In this case, if you increase the RemoteTimeOut value on the exporting server will help. By default, that value is 10, but MSFT recommended to increase it up to 1 hours.

here is PowerShell for it.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
$SharePointContentDeployment = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Administration.ContentDeploymentConfiguration]::GetInstance()
$SharePointContentDeployment.RemoteTimeout = 3600
$SharePointContentDeployment.Update()
```

[Changing the Time Out value of Content Deployment for SharePoint Server 2010/2013 with PoSH!](http://gokan.ms/2015/03/25/changing-the-time-out-value-of-content-deployment-for-sharepoint-server-20102013-with-posh/)

[Timeouts during content deployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795107(v=office.12).aspx#Section10)

Comment: I'll check and revert